# how to send a post request using Visual C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a authentication page with a website from a windows app using XAML and C#.

i have tried using the following code:

```
private void SubmitData()
    {
        try
        {
            string user = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://charnycoding.info/WebRequestPOST.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but when compiling it show error that request.ContentType does not have any definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some research

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275279/Developing-WCF-Restful-Services-with-GET-and-POST

Introduction
In this article, we will see how to create WCF REST based service. In this example, we will define two methods, GetSampleMethod (method type is GET) & PostSampleMethod (method type is POST).

GET method will take input as String & returns formatted String.
POST method will take input as XML (user registration) & return status string.
Note: One should have basic knowledge of what is WCF, why WCF & my article will discuss HOW to use WCF with webHttpBinding.

We will divide this article into the below sections:

Define WCF Service
Define Interface
Define Class
Implement POST & GET methods
Define Configuration for WCF Service
Service Configuration
Behavior Configuration
Smoke test WCF service (before client uses it)
Implement client code to use WCF service
Define WCF Service
Open VS 2010 & Select new Project, then select WCF & select WCF Service Application & name it as WCF Rest Based.
Now add new Service class to this application as “MyService.svc”
Open interface IMservice.cs & add the below code:
OperationContract: PostSampleMethod
WebInvoke Method Type = POST as we are implementing POST
URI Template defines the URL format by which this method is identified / linked. 
Note: MethodName, URI Template name & Operation Contract names may not be same means they can be different
PostSampleMethod will accept XML string as input in POST method. Using Stream as input parameter, we can de-serialize input data before using it.
Hide   Copy Code

```
[OperationContract(Name = “PostSampleMethod”)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = “POST”,
     UriTemplate = “PostSampleMethod/New”)]
    string PostSampleMethod(Stream data);
OperationContract name: GetSampleMethod
WebGet attribute defined method type is GET
Need to include below namespaces:
Hide   Copy Code
System.ServiceModel.Web;
System.ServiceModel
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.IO
[OperationContract(Name = “GetSampleMethod”)]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = “GetSampleMethod/inputStr/{name}”)]
    string GetSampleMethod(string name);
```

Open MyService.cs class and provide implementation for the methods defined in IMyService Interface as shown below:

Hide   Copy Code

```
public string PostSampleMethod(Stream data)
 {
    // convert Stream Data to StreamReader
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    // Read StreamReader data as string
    string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string returnValue = xmlString;
    // return the XMLString data
    return returnValue;
    }
    public string GetSampleMethod(string strUserName)
{
    StringBuilder strReturnValue = new StringBuilder();
    // return username prefixed as shown below
    strReturnValue.Append(string.Format
    (”You have entered userName as {0}”, strUserName));
    return strReturnValue.ToString();
    }
```

Define Configuration for WCF Service
Open web.config as we need to define configuration for our WCF Service. If you want our service to be accessed as part of webHttp, then we need to define webHttpBinding & mexHttpBinding.
In System.ServiceModel defined configuration as shown below. To know details about the below config configuration, check out the URL: https://ch1blogs.cognizant.com/blogs/279850/2011/10/18/service-end-point-not-found/.
Hide   Copy Code

```
<services>
  <service name=”WcfRestBased.MyService” 
behaviorConfiguration=”myServiceBehavior” >
    <endpoint name=”webHttpBinding”
              address=”"
              binding=”webHttpBinding”
              contract=”WcfRestBased.IMyService”
              behaviorConfiguration=”webHttp”
              >
            </endpoint>
    <endpoint name=”mexHttpBinding”
              address=”mex”
              binding=”mexHttpBinding”
              contract=”IMetadataExchange”
              />
  </service>
</services>
```

Service Name: To find what's to be given, right click the service & select ViewMarkup option.

Example, in my case, it is MyService.svc, look for Service attribute & use the complete string, in my case it is Service=”WcfRestBased.MyService”.

behaviorConfiguration: can be any name but this will be again used when we define behavior settings, in my case it is myServiceBehavior.

Endpoint for webHttpBinding

endpoint name: should be webHttpBinding if you are configuring for web access
address: we can leave it empty
binding: should be webHttpBinding
contract: should be Namespace.Interfacename. In my case, it is wcfRestBased.IMyService
behaviorConfiguration: should be webHttp
EndPoint for mexHttpBinding

These values should be same as shown above.

Now define Service behavior as shown below in System.ServiceModel. “mySeriveBehavior” name should match behaviorConfiguration name defined in Service tag (shown above):
Hide   Copy Code

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name=”myServiceBehavior” >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled=”true”/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults=”false” />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!– To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
    set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint 
    above before deployment –>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled=”true”/>
      <!– To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
    set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment 
    to avoid disclosing exception information –>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults=”false”/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name=”webHttp”>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Smoke Test WCF Service
Configure WCF Service in IIS
To check our WCF service is working properly, let's test it by opening MyService.svc in browser, in my case it is http://localhost/wcfrestbased/MyService.svc 
To test our GET method service, you can call it by http://localhost/wcfrestbased/MyService.svc/GetSampleMethod/inputStr/suryaprakash & this shows up data as “You have entered userName as suryaprakash”.
By this, we can confirm our service is working fine.
Implement Client Code to Use WCF Service
Create new website application which will act as client to access WCF services.
Add a textbox to default.aspx page & name it as txtResult & open Default.aspx.cs
Define below function which will call rest service to fetch the data. This method will call POSTSAMPLEMETHOD in service (MyService) implemented. Inline code comments are added.
Hide   Shrink    Copy Code

```
void CallPostMethod()
    {
        // Restful service URL
        string url = 
     “http://localhost/wcfrestbased/myservice.svc/PostSampleMethod/New“;

        // declare ascii encoding
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string strResult = string.Empty;
        // sample xml sent to Service & this data is sent in POST
        string SampleXml = @”<parent>” +
                “<child>” +
                    “<username>username</username>” +
                    “<password>password</password>” +
                “</child>” +
              “</parent>”;
        string postData = SampleXml.ToString();
        // convert xmlstring to byte using ascii encoding
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        // set method as post
        webrequest.Method = “POST”;
        // set content type
        webrequest.ContentType = “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”;
        // set content length
        webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        // get stream data out of webrequest object
        Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        // declare & read response from service
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

        // set utf8 encoding
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(”utf-8?);
        // read response stream from response object
        StreamReader loResponseStream = 
    new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        // read string from stream data
        strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        // close the stream object
        loResponseStream.Close();
        // close the response object
        webresponse.Close();
        // below steps remove unwanted data from response string
        strResult = strResult.Replace(”</string>”, “”);
            strResult = strResult.Substring(strResult.LastIndexOf(’>
```

Now let's go ahead and implement code to call GETSAMPLEMETHOD from client application. The below code has inline comments:
Hide   Copy Code

```
void CallGetMethod()
    {
        // Restful service URL
        string url = “http://localhost/wcfrestbased/myservice.svc/
        GetSampleMethod/inputStr/suryaprakash“;
        string strResult = string.Empty;
        // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        // set method as post
        webrequest.Method = “GET”;
        // set content type
        webrequest.ContentType = “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”;
        // declare & read response from service
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        // set utf8 encoding
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(”utf-8?);
        // read response stream from response object
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader
            (webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        // read string from stream data
        strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        // close the stream object
        loResponseStream.Close();
        // close the response object
        webresponse.Close();
        // assign the final result to text box
       txtResult.Text = strResult;
        }
```

Now go ahead and call the above methods to see the output of each method.